# getting incorrect count when counting a collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

this is my query

```
match ( user{displayName:'Mahmoud'})-[:LIKES]->(artists:ARTIST)-[:PLAYS]->(genres) with 
user,collect(distinct genres) as user_genres
match(users)-[:LIKES]-(artists:ARTIST)-[:PLAYS]->(common_genres) where common_genres in user_genres
with user,users,collect( distinct common_genres) as coll_common_genres
return user,users,coll_common_genres, count(coll_common_genres)
```

when counting the collection which in result coll_common_genres is 6 entries the common_genres_count gives me 1 and sometimes 4 what is the problem
[image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2nkb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this query should be a more efficient way to get the common genres for every relevant user pair (assuming the user nodes have a `User` label):

```
MATCH
  (user:User {displayName:'Mahmoud'})-[:LIKES]->(:ARTIST)-[:PLAYS]->(genre),
  (other:User)-[:LIKES]-(:ARTIST)-[:PLAYS]->(genre)
WITH user, other, COLLECT(DISTINCT genre) AS common_genres
RETURN user, other, common_genres, SIZE(common_genres) AS genre_count
```

When a `WITH` or `RETURN` clause uses an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT`), the non-aggregating terms in the same clause are used as "grouping keys". So `RETURN x, COUNT(x)` is equivalent to asking "for each distinct x, how many x's are there"? Obviously, the answer will always be 1 (unless `x` is `null`).

`SIZE` is not an aggregating function, so it returned what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

so i had to use `SIZE` because it's a list but i don't know why it's a list, if anyone could explain